# Access private variable from another class?

Tags: java

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I want to display the value of b (10) in my `info()` method, but when I run this code, the value of b is 0. Why does this happen?

```
class Alpha {
    public int a = 5;
    public void info() {
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
        Beta3 betaku;
        betaku = new Beta3();
        System.out.println("b = " + betaku.perolehB());
        System.out.println("Dipanggil pada " + this.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("----------");
    }
}
```

Here's the main class:

```
class Beta3 extends Alpha { 
private int b;
public  void isiB(int b){
    this.b=b;
    }
public int perolehB(){
    return b;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) { 
Beta3 varobjBeta;
varobjBeta = new Beta3();
varobjBeta.isiB(10); 
varobjBeta.info(); 

Alpha varobjAlpha; 
varobjAlpha = new Alpha(); 
varobjAlpha.info(); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thx for all reply,,
I fix some code in Beta3 class like above, but i'm still confuse how to fix `Alpha` Class ,,,

Comment: In Alpha you're showing the b value of betaku instance, that betaku instance has not initialized that value

Comment: So what must i do, to show b value?
if i delete that line it show error,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will never work, in the info method you wrote this:

```
Beta3 betaku;
betaku = new Beta3();
System.out.println("b = " + betaku.perolehB());
```

And ever will display 0(Because b is not initialized in the betaku instance, so the default is 0), you should delete that line, and pass the `b` value in some way, or override the info method in `Beta3` class.

```
class Beta3 extends Alpha
{
   //Another code 

   public void info()
   {
       // super.info(); if you wanna show the a value too
       System.out.println("b=" + this.b);
   }

   //Some other code
}
```

Or if you need to access that value from Alpha class:

```
class Alpha
{
    public void info(Beta3 aux)
    {
        this.info();
        aux.info();
    }
}
```

Then in main you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
       Beta3 varobjBeta;
       varobjBeta = new Beta3();
       varobjBeta.isiB(10); 


      Alpha varobjAlpha; 
      varobjAlpha = new Alpha(); 
      varobjAlpha.info(varobjBeta); 
}
```

Comment: thx for your response but
How to pass b value,, to alpha class,,

Comment: Passing the value is not the best choice, is better to implement the info method in Beta3 class, and print the b value there not in the Alpha's info method

Answer (score 0):

Make line 4 of your `main()` method, `beta_ku.info();`. Your other calls to `.info` aren't working because you haven't called `isiB` and they're defaulting to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you write new Beta3, a new object of type Beta3 is created, with a new pair of attributes. If you want the value of an attribute you set in a previous object, just pass the reference of that object to the method and fetch the value from it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are asking for the value of an *instance* of `Beta3`, which never initializes its value anyways and Java automatically initializes ints to 0 (for some reason).

`beta_ku` should print out 10 correctly, but `varobjBeta` does not set its `b` value.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of `Beta3` in your `info` call to `Alpha` does not have its `b` value set.  Therefore, it is initialized at instantiation to `0`.

The real reason this happens is due to the way [initial values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) are established, per the JLS:

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created. ...

...which in general, means that all primitives are initialized to some form of zero, and all objects are initialized to `null`.

How would you get around this?  Either create an instance by hand of `Beta3` and pass that to the instance of `Alpha`, or just use `Beta3` to print its own `info`.

Observe that `beta_ku` would work fine, if you were calling `info` - for that instance, `b` is defined to `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
betake = new Beta3();
```

When you instantiate the `betake` it just assign the default values to the attributes of the class `Beta3`. Here the attribute of the class `Beta3` is `b`.

Below is a table of default values of class variables by type:

```
    Type                     default
--------------------------------------------------------
   boolean                     false
   int                          0
   float                       0.0
   char                       /u0000
   reference type              null
```

So in you class `Beta3` `b` is `int` so the it gets the default value of `0`. You need to call `isiB(int b)` to set the intended value to `b` or you have to write a parameterized con structure to set the value of `b` i.e.

```
public Beta3(int bb){
  this.b= bb;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

```
    Beta3 betaku;
    betake = new Beta3();
    betake.isiB(10);
    System.out.println("b = " + betaku.perolehB());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thx for your explanation, but how to get value of b in 
`System.out.println("b = " + betaku.perolehB());` in Alpha class

Comment: @AepSaepudin just create a parameterized con structure like i have shown.